# Rails: Devise Session Expiry with SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, certificate-expiry

The [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/security.html#session-expiry) on Security, under "2.9 Session Expiry" gives following example code:

```
class Session < ApplicationRecord
  def self.sweep(time = 1.hour)
    if time.is_a?(String)
      time = time.split.inject { |count, unit| count.to_i.send(unit) }
    end
 
    delete_all "updated_at < '#{time.ago.to_s(:db)}'"
  end
end
```

How do I connect the model to Devise / to the Devise SessionController? Will Devise use the model? Will it do so automatically or are further steps necessary? Isn't this example specific to Rails' own cookie/session management? If so, what would be the proper complement with Devise / Warden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are really useful if you’re building your own auth system, but Devise can handle this for you.

In your user model, add the `:timeoutable` attribute to your existing `devise` statement.

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can then specify the timeout duration, e.g.:

```
config.timeout_in 30.minutes
```

If a one-size-fits-all timeout limit doesn’t meet your needs, you have a couple of other options:

1. If you have different models that have their own sign in paths and different timeout limits, you can add `timeout_in` to each `devise_for` declaration
2. If you have a flag in your user model (e.g., some users have `admin: true`) you can add a `#timeout_in` method to your model (see [this entry in the Devise wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically)).

Most of the time, though, using the config file is the best, and easiest, way to go.